# How to calculate marginal utility with two goods?

Tags: microeconomics, utility, marginal

I'm just getting started as an amateur into microeconomics and I really can't understand this thing about marginal utility when more than one good is involved:

Let's say I have the utility function ***U = x(y+1)***.

Now, from what I've studied, I  think that the marginal utilities for x and y should be:

*MU<sub>x</sub> = y+1

MU<sub>y</sub> = x*

I just don't get how to arrive there "mathematically", and I fear I wouldn't be able to find the marginal utilities of a more complex function, for example ***U = x(x+y)***

Could you help me?
Thank you!

Comment: Have you studied differential calculus?

Comment: I know how to find the derivative of a single-variable function, but I've never done it with two variables

Comment: It's basically the same, but called a partial derivative.  The marginal utility of $x$ is just $dU/dx$, treating $y$ as if it's a constant.  This is exactly what you've already done for your first utility function.

Comment: Take a look at [**partial derivative**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative).

Comment: It was quite easy then. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite simple to answer given you know a bit of multivariable differential calculus. You're looking for *partial* derivatives of the utility function.

So, given $$U(x,y) = x(y+1)$$ we have $$\frac{\partial U}{\partial x} = y+1$$ and $$\frac{\partial U}{\partial y} = x$$.

These are the goods' marginal utilities.